# Overload Library Class Methods with Magento 1.6v or higher

Tags: magento, methods, overloading

I have Magento version 1.6 and I want to like overload a method in a class which is located in `{root}/lib folder`. I have seen that there are no problems If I want to overload magento methods in the `{root}/app/code/mage folder`.

But my problem is, how can I overload specific methods in a class from magento library lib folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, the only way to override the lib class file is to use the same folder structure as that of lib in app/code/local pool. 
For example if you want to override

```
lib/Varien/Image.php
```

then you should copy the file to:

```
app/code/local/Varien/Image.php
```

But in case of lib class's method overriding. i don't think if that's possible unless you modify the autoload classes.

Thanks

Comment: See app/Mage.php include_path lines.